# Cassandra PHP PDO not retrieving all records

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra

I'm attempting to work Cassandra 2.0 with PHP and the PDO extension.
It seems to be working however I'm having trouble retrieving records.

My code is as follows

```
// Connect to two hosts
 $dsn = "cassandra:host=localhost;port=9160,host=localhost,port=9160";
 $db = new PDO($dsn);
// Select Keyspace
 $db->exec("USE mykeyspace");
// Create and Excecute query
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
 $result = $stmt->execute();
// Dump to data
 var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
```

And this is the result of my var_dump

array(3) { [0]=> array(6) { ["user_id"]=> int(1745) [0]=> int(1745) [""]=> string(5) "smith" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(4) "john" [3]=> string(5) "smith" } [1]=> array(6) { ["user_id"]=> int(1744) [0]=> int(1744) [""]=> string(3) "doe" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(4) "john" [3]=> string(3) "doe" } [2]=> array(6) { ["user_id"]=> int(1746) [0]=> int(1746) [""]=> string(5) "smith" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(4) "john" [3]=> string(5) "smith" } }

The data is there, but it's not organized at all. Why there no fname is there which one of the names of my columns. The data is there but some of it only another numeral array keys.

The table structure is the Cassandra sample (getting started) data as follows

```
 user_id | fname | lname
---------+-------+-------
    1745 |  john | smith
    1744 |  john |   doe
    1746 |  john | smith
```

Have I done something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the table structure of `users` table ?

Comment: I've edited to question

Comment: Can you try with `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` & post the array you get ?

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["user_id"]=> int(1745) [""]=> string(5) "smith" } [1]=> array(2) { ["user_id"]=> int(1744) [""]=> string(3) "doe" } [2]=> array(2) { ["user_id"]=> int(1746) [""]=> string(5) "smith" } }

Answer (score 0):

try change your driver this cassandra pdo is very old , im use dataStax and work very well